# How to set source and target in JSPlumb dynamically

Tags: json, jsplumb

I am using jsplumb go show pictorial view of all devices connected to switch. I am following below approach, please comment in case if it's not as per standard.

1. Creating map of all the devices which are connected in the network, and dynamically create all devices on screen using innerHtml.
2. Create mapping json which contain which devices are connected to which device.
3. I now iterate json using javascript and create source and target for all devices on screen.

Problem:
When I iterate through json, source and target is not able to set in the below code.

```
var result = JSON.parse(devicePaths);
for (var i in result) { 
  var _source = new String(result[i]["source"]);
  var _target = new String(result[i]["target"]);
  var _endpoint = new String(result[i]["endpoint"]);
  console.log('_source ' + _source); //this gives me proper value
  console.log('_target ' + _target); //this gives me proper value
  console.log('_endpoint ' + _endpoint);
  instance = jsPlumb.getInstance({
    PaintStyle : {
      lineWidth : 1,
      strokeStyle : "#567567",
      outlineColor : "black",
      outlineWidth : 1
    }
  });
  common = {
    anchors : [ "BottomCenter", "BottomCenter" ],
    endpoints : [ "Dot", "Blank" ]
  }
  instance.connect({
    source : _source,
    target : _target,
    detachable : false,
    endpoint : _endpoint
    }, common);
  instance.draggable(_source);
  }
});
```

Same works if I hardcode source and target values as source : `rx_1` and target `masterSwitch`.

Comment: try moving the `jsPlumb.getInstance line` outside the for loop or simply use `jsPlumb` instead of `instance` everywhere.

Comment: i solved it, actually source take selector and not string in my case i was passing it as string value and it was failing.

Comment: Giving string also works. `https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/demo/home/demo.js` source for [KitchenSink](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/demo/home/dom.html)

Comment: In my case i am generating html dynamically by using inner html. So somehow it was not taking string directly so i did : $("#" + _source).attr("id") to get selector id.

Comment: I still don't think, that's the root-cause, but glad you worked it out!